# Do Mementos requests ever expire?

Tags: persona-5

In Persona 5, there are requests for the Phantom Thieves to take care of in Mementos, similar in vein to the requests in Tartarus in Persona 3. However, the requests in Persona 3 were listed with a specific expiration date. I cannot find any sort of expiry date on the requests in Persona 5.

Are there no expiration dates, meaning I can wait until the end of the game to complete them all at once, or do they expire after some unmentioned time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time limit you have is the day of the final dungeon, i.e.

> 22 December

Source: [Gamefaqs post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835628-persona-5/75203944) and [GearNuke guide](http://gearnuke.com/persona-5-guide-find-complete-mementos-requests/) (extract below)

> These requests can be obtained through mementos and they need to be
> completed before
>
> > 12/22
>
> so make sure you attempt all of them in order
> to get the associated trophy for them. Each of these requests can be
> attempted at any time although some of them have a certain requirement
> like doing a part time job at one of the 3 locations.

Comment: So basically, there is no expiration date. Curse the notification panel from not hiding the spoilers :(

Comment: if it is not existing yet, it should be a request for improvement on Arqade meta